# UILabel need to setNumberOfLines to fit my text size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uilabel

I have a `UILabel`. I need to set the number of lines to fit to it's text.

Comment: The resizing of `UILabel`'s frame is already made

Comment: how about 0 (as in "as many lines as needed")?

Comment: Wow. Fantastic solution!!! :) I didn't know that `setNumberOfLines:0` is "as many lines as needed". Please answer my question with your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `numberOfLines` property to 0, which removes any line limit and uses as many lines as needed.